# Redis provision via ansible

Tags: redis, ansible

I trying to check is redis running on my server. Installed with ansible.

```
# Ansiblefile
role 'DavidWittman.redis'

# provision.yml
...
- tasks:
  - name: redis | ensure service up and running
    service: name=redis enabled=yes state=started
```

After get:

```
TASK: [redis | ensure service up and running] *********************************
```

`failed: [default] => {"failed": true}`

```
msg: service not found: redis

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

What is the right way to check it?

Comment: and you are able to see that the service actually does exist on host in question? Can you post full play and full output?

Comment: ps  show that is running

Comment: ansible doesn't use `ps` to check if a service is running or not. Again: "and you are able to see that the service actually does exist on host in question? Can you post full play and full output?"

Comment: I went to server using ssh, in console ps show, i meant this.

Comment: The service is probably called redis-server, not redis

Comment: redis, redis-server, sentinel, and other most using names tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this ansible role need to use redis_6379 or redis_$portnumber